# Cannot bind to controller without directive 'searchBox's controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I am trying to create a directive that essentially wraps an `input`. As such I want to pass a number of attributes/arguments to the directive such as `ng-model`.

However I am having trouble getting it all working, at the moment I am getting the aforementioned error when I include the directive in the page.

```
interface ISearchBoxDirectiveScope extends angular.IScope {
    ngModel: string;
    placeholderText: string;
}

class SearchBoxDirectiveController {

    static $inject = ["$scope"];

    constructor(
        private $scope: ISearchBoxDirectiveScope) {
        console.log("This doesnt get hit", $scope);
    }

    public clearSearchTerm() {
        console.log("here");
        this.$scope.ngModel = "";
    }
}

class SearchBoxDirective implements angular.IDirective {

    restrict = "E";
    replace = true;
    scope = {
        ngModel: "=",
        placeholderText: "@"
    };
    templateUrl = "app/directives/searchBox/searchBox.template.html";
    controller: SearchBoxDirectiveController;
    controllerAs = "$ctrl";
    bindToController = true;

    public link: (scope: ISearchBoxDirectiveScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void;

    constructor() {

        SearchBoxDirective.prototype.link = ($scope: ISearchBoxDirectiveScope, $element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {

            console.log("SearchBoxDirective.prototype.link", $scope, attrs);
        }
    }

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = () => new SearchBoxDirective();

        directive.$inject = [];

        return directive;
    }
}

angular
    .module("app.directives")
    .directive("searchBox", SearchBoxDirective.factory());
```

And Im calling it like so

```
<search-box ng-model="$ctrl.rightSideFilter" placeholder-text="Search Vehicles"></search-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you want to access ng-model, since you are inheriting the scope from controller, rightSideFilter should be available to you on scope. Also, you can try the following.

```
   interface ISearchBoxDirectiveScope extends angular.IScope {
    rightSideFilter: string;
    placeholderText: string;
}
```

and

```
scope = {
'rightSideFilter': = '?rightSideFilter',
 ///any other
}
```

and assuming that if those are the only values your looking for then you can make directive work in isolation.

```
export class SearchBoxDirective implements angular.IDirective {

    restrict = "E";
    replace = true;
    scope = {
        ngModel: "=",
        placeholderText: "@"
    };
    templateUrl = "app/directives/searchBox/searchBox.template.html";
```

and your HTML syntax to

```
<search-box right-side-filter="$ctrl.rightSideFilter" place-holder-text="Search Vehicles"></search-box>
```